# UIImage scale and tile

Tags: image, uikit, scale, tiling

Is it possible to show a UIImage in a UIImageView such that the image is both, scaled and tiled?

for example, it should be scaled at 2 times it's actual resolution, but tiled across the full size of the UIImageView.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tile"];
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:0.5 orientation:image.imageOrientation];
[self.myImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage]];
```